# How to save the outputtext value to the object and then to the Database?

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I'm very new to JSF and Hibernate, I found some tutorials and I understood almost everything but there is something very simple I didn't understand yet and I can`t realize by myself how to do it;

`1.This is my html page`

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
   <h:outputLabel value="Title:"/>
   <h:inputText value='#{Activity.title}' />
 </h:panelGrid>
```

`2.This is my save method at activityController`

```
public void saveActivity(String title){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Activity activity = new Activity(title);
        session.save(activity);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**My doubt is: How do I get what my user types at the OutputText in the HTML page and send it to my saveActivity method?**

Comment: The question is broad and it is not clear what do you know/don't you know about JSF. Could you post the **whole** xhtml (ok, not all fields but the structure).

Comment: Sorry @SJuan76, I was trying to make it simple to read. I think no code would be needed, the bolded question was pretty simple. I just didn't know I could call a method within the #{}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Form and an Submit Button:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
   <h:outputLabel value="Title:"/>
   <h:inputText value='#{activityBean.title}' />
 </h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton action="#{activityBean.saveActivity()}" value="Save" />
</h:form>
```

Then, either make your Controller a Managed Bean with Annotation @SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "activityBean") or use a Class for it and give it a reference to your Controller.

Good Luck :)

Comment: The scope can be any (from `Request` to `Application`) or not specificated at all (which default to `Request`). Anyway +1 because the intent is good, I think it answers the question (although I still think the OP description is too vague) and because welcome to SO.

Comment: Well, I didn't know I could call a method within "#{}" . So yes, it answers my question. Thank you! :)